# Динамическая передача данных на Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Есть форма в которую через `Ajax` подгружаются поля. Каждому полю присвоен `id`, например `birthdayosoba_0`, `birthdayosoba_1` и т.д. Есть также поле с количеством полей которое мне нужно добавить. В самом скрипте я достаю количество полей и присваиваю значение переменной. Потом в цикле провожу присвоение динамичным переменным динамичные значения. А дальше мне нужно выбросить полученные значения на обработчик через `Ajax`.

Код Js:

```
function osoby_calc2() {
    var kil_osoby = document.getElementById('kil_osoby').value;
    for (var i = 0; i < kil_osoby; i++) {
        window['point_' + i] = document.getElementById("birthdayosoba_" + i).value;
        alert(point_0); //чисто для проверки работоспособности
    }
    $("#osoby_calc3").load("osoby_calc.php", {
        kil_osoby : kil_osoby
    });

}
```

Когда убираю:

```
for (var i = 0; i < kil_osoby; i++) {
    window['point_' + i] = document.getElementById("birthdayosoba_" + i).value;
    alert(point_0); //чисто для проверки работоспособности
}
```

то данные нормально переносятся в обработчик. Но если присутствует часть кода, тогда `alert()` срабатывает, но данные не уходят.

Где я ошибся? 
P.S.: очень попрошу не давать советов по поводу массивов и т.д. нет возможности их использовать, нужно поправить данный пример. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Проверьте, для всех `i` есть `document.getElementById("birthdayosoba_" + i).value`?

Comment: С этим разобрался но теперь проблема еще большего характера возникал(((

Comment: В чем проблема была? Что теперь не так?

Comment: Проблема была в том что я когда написал скрипт для теста, то вручную вбил количество циклов, а в реальности полей было меньше, вот потому то и не срабатывало.А тепер у меня проблема по серйозней: есть чатсь кода '$("#osoby").load("osoby.php", { kil_osoby: kil_osoby
         });' в ней передаются разные параметры. Вот как мне засунуть в передачу параметров вот новые переменные с их динамическими значениями?!

Answer (score 2):

alert не работает внутри функции - выдает последнее значение, используйте замкнутое выражение.

Comment: Алерт срабатует нормально.Сообщение выводится. Проблема что `$("#osoby_calc3").load("osoby_calc.php", {
        kil_osoby : kil_osoby
    });` не работает.Мне алерт нужен лишь для того чтоб увидеть что данные передаются. Его можно и удалить вовсе

Comment: Мне кажется, что Вы не правы. [Опровержение](http://jsfiddle.net/xngv8qgu/). Думаю Вы имели в виду, что `alert` приостанавливает выполнение скрипта.

Comment: Я его удалил но процесс не поменялся. Я вот только что сидел и понял что даже такая архитектура не поможет даже если я разберусь с проблемой. Дело в том что мне нужно передать все сформированные данные в обработчик. И думаю что без массивов мне не обойтись как бы я этого не хотел

Comment: @Александр, в чем проблема массивов?

Comment: @Rolandius, забавно, что внутри функции alert работает, ранее этого замечено не было. вот без функции - alert не работает  http://jsfiddle.net/xngv8qgu/1/

Comment: Вы правы, алерт действительно имеет такую скудную функцию, но даже убрав его я не могу запустить передачу данных в обработчик

Comment: А проблема массивов заключается в отсутствие опыта передачи массивов в яве.

Comment: Только что уивдел свою ошибку.Я вручную вбил количество проходов по циклу, а количество полей біло меньше. ВОт поєтому и не срабатывал скрипт. Но все же хотел бы услышать адекватное мнение знающих людей

Comment: Кстати сделал вот так:
  `  <script>
function osoby_calc2(){
var a=3;
for( var i=0;i<a;i++){
document.write(window['id_' + i] = document.getElementById("id_"+i).value);
}

 
    
}   
</script>`
Но почемуто вижу только первое значение

Comment: @Александр, я же говорю - используйте замкнутые выражения (function(){})(). И никогда не применяйте document.write

Comment: С замкнутыми выражениями очень интересно. А как мне сюда засунуть новые переменные `$("#osoby_calc3").load("osoby_calc.php", { kil_osoby : kil_osoby });` ?

Comment: Не используйте алерт никогда. Для тестирования кода применяйте только console.log()